# black fish shape on screen

Tags: laptop

I bought a Sony Viao 8 weeks ago and when I turned it on there was a fish shaped black smear on the screen. The laptop has never been moved from the desk or damaged in any way.

Noel Leaming are saying its impact damage but this is not true. What could have caused this?
They are refusing to repair or replace.

Comment: Can you post an image of it?

Answer (score 1):

> What could have caused this?

- impact damage
- heat
- pressure

Effected by

- brothers
- cats
- cleaning ladies
- aliens

If you are sure it is a manufacturing defect, take the matter up with your local trading standards or equivalent QUANGO for your locale.

Comment: Gotta watch them tricky aliens. If you can catch 'em, that is.